# clickable headings that expand with details underneath in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I didn't really know how to title this question or how to describe what I'm looking to do but I essentially want to replicate how this site...https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/ has formatted its API documentation. I'm looking to do the same but is there an angular directive that does something similar to the link above?

Answer (score 3):

What you're after is called an Accordion, and yes there is one here created by the AngularUI Team:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#accordion